# How do I exclude package from publishing with sbt?

Tags: scala, sbt

I want to publish a library, which has some usage examples in runnable classes. When I call `sbt run` , it finds them and asks me, which of the main classes found I want, and then launches it. That's neat, I'd like this behaviour to stay. But those examples complicate my Android build ( more proguard configs ), so I don't want them in published artefacts.

For now, I totally exclude them, putting this into build.sbt :

```
excludeFilter in Compile ~= { _ ||
  new FileFilter {
    def accept(f: File) = f.getPath.containsSlice("/examples/")
  } }
```

then, when I run `sbt publish-local`, I get jars without examples, but then one can't get the library source and see how it works, with just typing `sbt run`. How can I exclude examples package only from publishing, but let it still be compiled for local runs?

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend splitting examples into another subproject instead.